# Cannot create HyperLedger network

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hyperledger

I'm trying to generate hyperledger channel, when i run it on local works without problems, but when i run on AWS ec2, i ve problems, there its my problem:

```
$ ./network.sh up createChannel -c mychannel -ca
Creating channel 'mychannel'.
If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb with crypto from 'Certificate Authorities'
Bringing up network
LOCAL_VERSION=2.2.1
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.2.2
Local fabric binaries and docker images are out of  sync. This may cause problems.
CA_LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.9
CA_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.9
Generate certificates using Fabric CA's
Creating network "net_test" with the default driver
Creating ca_orderer ... 
Creating ca_org2    ... error
Creating ca_org1    ... 
Creating ca_orderer ... error
ERROR: for ca_org2  Cannot start service ca_org2: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown

ERROR: for ca_orderer  Cannot start service ca_orderer: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: RunCreating ca_org1    ... done

ERROR: for ca_org2  Cannot start service ca_org2: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown

ERROR: for ca_orderer  Cannot start service ca_orderer: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

full output there:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GmwRpwPxNZ/

If i try just network up:

```
./network.sh up
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' 
LOCAL_VERSION=2.2.1
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.2.2
Local fabric binaries and docker images are out of  sync. This may cause problems.
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
WARNING: Found orphan containers (ca_org1, ca_orderer, ca_org2) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating orderer.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... error
Creating orderer.example.com    ... error
ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown

Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
r init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: killed, stdout: , stderr:: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
dca2d9f83dca   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        9 seconds ago   Created                 0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp             peer0.org1.example.com
367cac851efb   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        9 seconds ago   Up Less than a second   7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
80395383fdde   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"                9 seconds ago   Created                 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp             orderer.example.com
374e559f3a40   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   4 minutes ago   Created                 7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp   ca_org2
ab485b1041f2   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes            0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp             ca_org1
9588650913c8   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   4 minutes ago   Created                 7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9054->9054/tcp   ca_orderer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low memory on machine, that was problem